# Android stylable atributes understanding: actionBarIconColor, actionBarInsetStart, etc

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm doing code review of [Google I/O Android App](https://github.com/google/iosched)
So, I found this code in `attrs.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="BaseTheme">
    <attr name="actionBarIconColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="actionBarInsetStart" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="spinnerBarInsetStart" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="popupItemBackground" format="reference" />
    <attr name="photoItemForeground" format="reference" />
    <attr name="photoItemForegroundBorderless" format="reference" />

</declare-styleable>
```

**link:** https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L18-L25

and the continuation of it in `styles.xml`:

```
    <style name="Theme.IOSched.Base" parent="Theme">
        <item name="actionBarIconColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="actionBarInsetStart">@dimen/keyline_2</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_up</item>
        <item name="spinnerBarInsetStart">@dimen/keyline_2_minus_16dp</item>
        <item name="popupItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="photoItemForeground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="photoItemForegroundBorderless">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>

    ....
    </style>
```

**link:** https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml#L32-L38

I tried to find usage of this attributes *(Alt+F7 in **Intellij IDEA**)*, but only usage in generated code founded. And furthermore, this is ***not usage*** literally. This is just compiling all resource in one file or generated constants in `R.java` class. So actually it's the same. Look at this generated code for *`actionBarIconColor` attribute*:

```
public static final int actionBarIconColor=0x7f010022;
...
public static final int BaseTheme_actionBarIconColor = 0;
```

That's all usages, that I could find.

Of course you can say, that **this is reference which nevere used** and you will be right.
 But just for experiment, I tried to change

```
<item name="actionBarIconColor">#fff</item>
```

to

```
<item name="actionBarIconColor">#f00</item>
```

And result you can see at this screenshot:
[image]

---

## My questions:

1). Why color changed if `actionBarIconColor` never used?
2). What is the purpose of `actionBarIconColor, actionBarInsetStart, spinnerBarInsetStart, popupItemBackground` etc. attributes? They not uses to set *style* of something, but why Google engineers created this attributes?